# How to mix static class factory method and instance method

Tags: typescript

When I add an instance method `addField` in the code below, the Typescript compiler produces an error for all my factory static method `withError` and `withSuccess`:

> Property 'addField' is missing in type '{ isSuccess: true; ... }' but required in type 'WebError'.

```
export class WebError {
    isSuccess: boolean; 
    errTitle: string;
    errSummary: string;
    errFields: WebErrorField[];
    constructor() {
            this.errFields = [];
    }
    static withError(errTitle: string = "Unknown Error", errSummary: string = "Unknown Error"): WebError {
            return { isSuccess: false, errFields: [], errTitle: errTitle, errSummary: errSummary };
    }
    static withSuccess(errTitle: string = "", errSummary: string = ""): WebError {
            return { isSuccess: true, errFields: [], errTitle: errTitle, errSummary: errSummary };
    }
    addField(fieldName: string, fieldError: string) {
            this.errFields.push({ fieldName: fieldName, fieldError: fieldError });
    }
}
```

What should I have done differently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because `withError()` and `withSuccess()` return a `WebError`. `addField()` is a property of `WebError`, but the object your two static methods return does not include it. You could fix it by returning an actual `WebError` from the static methods, instead of just an object that satisfies its interface.

```
export class WebError {
  isSuccess: boolean;
  errTitle: string;
  errSummary: string;
  errFields: WebErrorField[] = [];

  constructor(params: {
    isSuccess: boolean;
    errTitle: string;
    errSummary: string;
  }) {
    this.isSuccess = params.isSuccess;
    this.errTitle = params.errTitle;
    this.errSummary = params.errSummary;
  }

  static withError(
    errTitle: string = 'Unknown Error',
    errSummary: string = 'Unknown Error',
  ): WebError {
    return new WebError({isSuccess: false, errTitle, errSummary});
  }

  static withSuccess(errTitle: string = '', errSummary: string = ''): WebError {
    return new WebError({isSuccess: true, errTitle, errSummary});
  }

  addField(fieldName: string, fieldError: string) {
    this.errFields.push({fieldName: fieldName, fieldError: fieldError});
  }
}
```